# AngularJS page blank after refresh

Tags: angularjs, state

I am building a web aplication with AngularJS. I am using ui-router and I have defined states like this:

```
//appContacts.js
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var app = angular
        .module('appContacts', ['ui.router', 'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination'])
        .config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
                        function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
                            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
                            $stateProvider
                                 .state("home", {
                                     url: "/",
                                     templateUrl: "views/contactsView.html",
                                     controller: "contactsController",
                                     controllerAs: "vm"
                                 })
                                 .state("organization", {
                                     url: "/organizations/:Id",
                                     templateUrl: "views/organizationDetail.html",
                                     params: { Id: null },
                                     controller: "organizationsController",
                                     controllerAs: "vm"
                                 })
                                .state("contact", {
                                    url: "/contact/:Id",
                                    templateUrl: "views/contactDetails.html",
                                    params: { Id: null },
                                    controller: "contactsDetailController",
                                    controllerAs: "vm"
                                })

                            $locationProvider.html5Mode({
                                enabled: true,
                                requireBase: false,
                                rewriteLinks: true
                            });

                            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
                        }
        ]);
})();
```

I get requested information from the Database using HTTP methods. I have two issues:

1. When I refresh the page the page get blank. Any idea what I am doing wrong?
2. The home page controller calls automatically the HTTP methods that populate a table using ng-repeat. That means that it is impossible to visit another page directly like http://localhost:50895/contact/the-id because there is not data stored. I always have to visit the home page to load the data. How could I save and make available that data to all pages/states/controllers?

EDIT:

I have 4 error shown in the console. 
[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angularjs/3208/angularjs-gotchas-and-traps/21798/things-to-do-when-using-html5mode#t=201610130617273024935

Answer (score 0):

1. Could you please debug it and check the browser console for any errors or exceptions??
2. There are three ways in which you can pass the data around:

a) Use **$rootScope** , but this is not considered as proper coding standard

b) Make use of the inbuilt **.service()** provided by AngularJs, this is a singleton object, means the value set into it in the first controller can be used anywhere down the line. But the value will be erased if you refresh the page.This is considered as better coding standard than using **$rootScope**

c) You can make use of **localStorage** or **sessionStorage**, using this the data can be retrieved even after the page refresh. Data will be stored as string, so parsing is needed.

There is one more way to store the data , Cookies. But this is used to store small string values.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have edited the post adding the errors I have in the console as you requested. 2.- At the moment I am using a service to pass data from one controller to another, but as you say, it does not help when I refresh the page. I will give a try to localStorage.

Comment: You did mention that page goes blank if you refresh the page, can you please tell which route you were in when u refreshed the page.

Comment: It happens in everypage/route, I always have to go to the homepage and restart the process again

Comment: Looks like u hv a version issue, try to downgrade Angular to 1.5.3